# where is the zlib framework in xcode 4.x

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, zlib

I am just trying to set up a new application that I am hoping to take advantage of ASIHTTPRequest framework.. however in their [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)  they state that you have to link against CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices, CoreGraphics and zlib frameworks. 
The only problem being there is no zlib framework.. their are libz.dylib files however their are several of them and I am unsure which are suitable, if someone could please let me know what to do here that would be awesome!

Comment: Well I tried libz.dylib it seemes to have resolved the errors I was getting however not 100% sure this is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're right using libz.dylib.